# New Catalog price rule condition in Magento

Tags: magento, magento-1.9, rule, catalog, price

I want a new catalog price rule condition and input type as as text for its value and save its value into database.
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/1U9BJ.png)

Comment: In your new condition which type of data you want to add?

Comment: any kind of data, i want a text box.